# RegEx for extracting mobile numbers with a specific format

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have an sms text from mysql. The text contains 5 types of text. Firstly a 11 mobile number ( 01***********) format. And two amounts of money, One transaction ID with 10 digit uppercase letters and number and a date-time. I need to extract each of the text and store it in different variables.

Example text: Cash In Tk **500.00** from **01789788881** successful. Fee Tk **0.00**. Balance Tk 4,145.08. TrxID **6E63D2OS4R** at **06/05/2019 20:24**.

So far i tried to extract the phone number

```
$sms_text = $result['sms_text'];

preg_match('/\b\d{3}\s*-\s*\d{3}\s*-\s*\d{4}\b/', $sms_text, $sms_from);

echo $sms_from;
echo $cash_in_amount;
echo $fee;
echo $ trx_id;
echo $trx_time;
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex, and extract the three values from group1, group2 and group3 and of course I can assume here that your SMS text would be in same format.

```
from\s+(\d+).*([a-zA-Z0-9]{10})\s+at\s+(.*)
```

**[Regex Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/UhLJaO/1)**

**[PHP Code Demo](https://rextester.com/WIIQX46442)**

```
$sms = 'Cash In Tk 500.00 from 01789788881 successful. Fee Tk 0.00. Balance Tk 4,145.08. TrxID 6E63D2OS4R at 06/05/2019 20:24';
preg_match_all('/from\s+(\d+).*([a-zA-Z0-9]{10})\s+at\s+(.*)/', $sms, $matches);
print('Mobile Number: '.$matches[1][0]."\n");
print('Transaction Id: '.$matches[2][0]."\n");
print('Date Time: '.$matches[3][0]."\n");
```

Output,

```
Mobile Number: 01789788881
Transaction Id: 6E63D2OS4R
Date Time: 06/05/2019 20:24
```

**Edit:**

For getting `Cash In Tk 500.00 and Fee Tk 0.00` you can use following regex,

```
(\S+)\s+from\s+(\d+).*Fee\s+Tk\s+(\S+)\..*([a-zA-Z0-9]{10})\s+at\s+(.*)
```

**[Regex Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/UhLJaO/2)**

**[Updated PHP Demo](https://rextester.com/OREAH25795)**

```
$sms = 'Cash In Tk 500.00 from 01789788881 successful. Fee Tk 0.00. Balance Tk 4,145.08. TrxID 6E63D2OS4R at 06/05/2019 20:24';
preg_match_all('/(\S+)\s+from\s+(\d+).*Fee\s+Tk\s+(\S+)\..*([a-zA-Z0-9]{10})\s+at\s+(.*)/', $sms, $matches);
print('Cash In Tk: '.$matches[1][0]."\n");
print('Mobile Number: '.$matches[2][0]."\n");
print('Fee Tk: '.$matches[3][0]."\n");
print('Transaction Id: '.$matches[4][0]."\n");
print('Date Time: '.$matches[5][0]."\n");
```

Prints,

```
Cash In Tk: 500.00
Mobile Number: 01789788881
Fee Tk: 0.00
Transaction Id: 6E63D2OS4R
Date Time: 06/05/2019 20:24
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. The sms text will be always in same format. I want to extract all groups in separate variable. Not in single one. How can i do that? Kindly share the full line php code

Comment: @TanjimaTani: Updated a sample code demo, where you can print/extract the value as you want. Let me know if you have any issues further.

Comment: Hi, Working fine. Also need the match for amounts: Cash In Tk `500.00` and Fee Tk `0.00` . Thanks

Comment: @TanjimaTani: Updated my answer. Hopefully that should be it.

Comment: Working perfectly. Thanks a million.

Comment: Glad to help @TanjimaTani :)